# Adding a note for a subscriber using Mailchimp API

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am having trouble adding a note to a subscriber using Mailchimp's API. Here's what I have:

```
$email = 'some@email.com';
$list = '123456';
$note = 'This is an example of a note.';

$apiKey = 'MY-API-KEY';
$memberId = md5(strtolower($email));
$dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
$url = 'https://'.$dataCenter.'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$list.'/members/'.$memberId.'/notes';

$json['note'] = $note;

$json = json_encode($json);

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                                                                 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($httpCode == 200) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Any ideas why these notes would not be saved? I've made sure the API key, the list ID and the email address are all correct.

The documentation page is here: https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/notes/

Comment: Please elaborate what happens after you execute your code. Does the value of `$httpCode` equal `200` after executing `curl_close($ch);`?